# what causes random (irregular and inconsistent) sound feedback through wires to speakers?

Tags: noise

I have a 3.5mm stereo jack from my laptop to a guitar amp I use as an external speaker. It's not the most ideal set up but sometimes I get feedback, a loud buzz and other times I do not. It runs across or nearby power and other various cables so that all makes sense.

What confuses me is specifically what happened just a few minutes ago. I plugged it in because I had to move the desk earlier. It sounded fine for 10 seconds and then loud static feedback slowly increased for about 5 seconds after 10 seconds of crisp sound. I repeat - good sound for 10 seconds, then the linear onset of static that continued. That is strange because what type of system would be quiet and good for the first while and then suddenly create feedback? I unplugged the cable and plugged it back in and it was the same story- about 10 seconds of good sound and then the coming feedback. I did it again and got the same - and I'm not moving the wire by the way. It's just laying there. I did it a fourth time and now it stays fine.

I am not actually looking for any kind of fix or solution. I want to know the physics of this because it's a curious anomaly. My theory is that the computer especially is a kind of black box where we are dealing with electronics vs electrical. The amp may have some of these aspects but the computer would have more. I also notice - and this probably ties in, that if I forget to turn the amp off it will stay silent until my computer goes to sleep and then a constant lower level static will start up, so it seems like there is an active feedback suppression system or ground or something within my computer physical or virtual architecture.

I want to learn more about all these topics, which will take a lot of study, but I thought it would be worth asking these specific ones here.

Comment: For the latter part, likely the PC turns off the audio circuits when it is off or nothing being played, so nothing is driving the amp and the amp picks up noise from the high impedance output. The amp has very high impedance and a lot of gain. Guitar amps are not intended for headphone or line level outputs.  When there are noises, would Bluetooth, wireless LAN or mobile phone happen to communicate at that time?

Comment: Are you asking about 'static' (hiss) sound or are you referring to feedback? These are completely different and unrelated phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

Electric fields and capacitive coupling cause voltage increases in the wire. Magnetic fields and inductive coupling including ground loops cause current noise in wires. Proper grounding and shielding reduce these effects. Read electromagnetic compatibility engineering by Henry W Ott

Answer (score 0):

A guess: Your audio signal is not balanced. There's a capacitive or even a galvanic ground loop ie. 2 separate routes between the amp ground and computer ground. Route  1 is the signal ground which is at the same time normally the cable shield. The 2nd route can be through the protective earth groundings of the power supply cables. That's often non-existent if the devices fulfill double insulation specs. But there still can be a heavy capacitive 2nd ground connection because generally to fulfill EMI emission limits the devices have big capacitors connected between the mains AC input and the low voltage circuitry ground. Without such capacitors the switchmode power supplies would be high power radio noise transmitters

Ground loops collect much noise. That's possible to neutralize by having balanced signals or isolation transformers in audio signals. An old trick is to break one of the protective ground connections, but that's a dangerous move. A fault could kill someone and connecting or disconnecting signal cables can fry the electronics due the mains AC voltage, no matter it comes through capacitors. Breaking a protective ground is definitely nothing that can be recommended.

To stay in truth we actually know nothing of your amp. If it happens to be a miniature device with rechargeable battery and you charge it through an USB connection the case is clear. A part of the charging current (=pulses) go through your audio signal ground and add some noise to the audio signal voltage. You must either to use an audio isolation transformer or to use a properly isolated USB charger to charge the amp battery.